# Animate Text Glint On Animated Text

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a button that loads more data into a datagrid when clicked. To indicate progress, I change the text of the button to change from "More" to "Loading..." where the periods are animated. Next, I wanted to add a "glint" effect so that the text catches your eye. If you've used an iPhone/iPod Touch, I'm thinking of the effect on the "Slide To Unlock" text of the lock screen.

To do so, I shift a middle, lighter gradient stop from left to right. Because the animation continuously loops, I used offsets outside of the valid range to create a delay between the times when the light gradient stop is actually visible.

I got this implemented but I can tell that for some reason, the light gradient is not starting at the left edge of the text. It starts at about the 'a' in the "Loading". I accepted that and it's been in place for a while, but I'm now coming back to it just to try to understand why. It seems like maybe it's using the measure of the original text when calculating the animation, but I thought the animations were supposed to apply to each other when in the same storyboard. Here is my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:EmptyBatchNumConverter x:Key="emptyBatchNumConverter" />

    <BeginStoryboard x:Key="bsbLoadingMore" x:Name="bsbLoadingMore">
        <Storyboard x:Name="sbLoadingMore">
            <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtBtnMoreText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" Duration="0:0:2" FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading." KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading.." KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading..." KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
            </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            <!--Animate the OffSet of the light gradient stop for a "glint" effect. Using -4.5 to 4.5 to delay the visible effect between repeats (and 
                              control the speed relative to the duration). Using an extra .4 seconds to offset the frequency from the text animation. -->
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="gs2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" From="-4.5" To="4.5" Duration="0:0:2.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<Button Name="btnMore" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource OasisGridMoreButton}" Click="btnMore_Click" Visibility="Visible" Height="16">
            <Button.Content>
                <TextBlock Name="txtBtnMoreText" MinWidth="48" Text="More..." /> <!--MinWidth = width of "Loading..."-->
            </Button.Content>
            <Button.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.2,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop x:Name="gs1" Color="Black"  Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop x:Name="gs2" Color="Cyan" Offset="-4.5"/>
                    <GradientStop x:Name="gs3" Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Foreground>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.2,0" EndPoint="1,1">
```

Change it to:

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
```

Here is the full test app I made (slowed down glint to see it better):

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bsbLoadingMore">
                <Storyboard x:Name="sbLoadingMore">
                    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtBtnMoreText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" Duration="0:0:2" FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading." KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading.." KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Loading..." KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
                    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <!--Animate the OffSet of the light gradient stop for a "glint" effect. Using -4.5 to 4.5 to delay the visible effect between repeats (and 
                                      control the speed relative to the duration). Using an extra .4 seconds to offset the frequency from the text animation. -->
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="gs2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" From="-4.5" To="4.5" Duration="0:0:5.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="btnMore"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,213,0,182" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
        <Button.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop x:Name="gs1" Color="Black"  Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="gs2" Color="Cyan" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="gs3" Color="Black" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Foreground>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtBtnMoreText" MinWidth="48" Text="More..." />
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

For some reason, it is not showing the `</Window>` at the end...

Comment: Wow. You know what they say, "Ask a stupid question, look stupid." I'd -1 myself if I could. Thank you.

This fixes the problem and really is good enough, but not quite working how I wanted. When gs2's offset is any value < 1, the text is all black. It's not until it is >=0 that it becomes visible. When it is = 0, the left side of the text is fully Cyan. So the fading right side of the gradient never "crosses over" the 'L'. It just turns cyan instantly. Is there anyway to have the gradient fully enter from the left and move past the right?